# How to Scatter then Reduce using MPI and c++

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to parallelize the computation of the norm2 of a vector (variable size). My approach was to first scatter the vector amoungs the processors, calculate the square and sum of each sub vectors and then reduce the reslut and apply the squareroot.

Here is my code :

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

double SquareSum(std::vector<double> & v) {

double res;

for (std::vector<double>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++){
    if (*it){
        res += (*it)*(*it);
    }
    else{
        it++;
    }
}

return res;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

std::vector<double> numbers;
double val;
while (std::cin >> val) numbers.push_back(val);



MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

int rank, size;

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

unsigned numbers_count = numbers.size();

MPI_Bcast(&numbers_count, 1, MPI_UNSIGNED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

unsigned local_share = numbers_count / size; // local_share is the floor function of numbers.size() / number of process


if (numbers_count % size > 0){
    ++local_share;  // if size is not a multiple of numbers.size() add 1 to local_share in order to make it "fit"
}

if (rank == 0){ 
numbers.resize(local_share*size); //resize numbers by adding null empty spot if necessary
}

//std::cout << "I'm" << rank << std::endl;
std::vector<double> local(local_share);

MPI_Scatter(&numbers, local_share, MPI_DOUBLE, &local, local_share, MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

double par_sum = SquareSum(local);

double sum = 0;


MPI_Reduce(&par_sum, &sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (rank == 0){

    std::cout << "norm : " << std::sqrt(sum);
}
MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
}
```

When I try to execute the programm I have this error :

"mpiexec noticed that process rank 2 with PID 9823 on node laptop exited on signal 11 (Segmentation fault)."

I suppose there is a problem with the scatter but I cannot figure ou what.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `&numbers` and `&local` are the addresses of the control structures of the vector objects, not the data they contain. Try `&numbers[0]` and `&local[0]` instead.

Comment: I change the code and I have the same error. But I've done some research and might be due to a lack of memory. (something like addind swap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the comment of @Hristo Iliev:

The size of `numbers` is likely not a multiple of size. Then, `local_share` becomes `numbers_count % size+1`. It is used as the size of the part each process retreives by `MPI_Scatter()`. As a result, the scattered vector must be of size `(numbers_count % size+1)*size`. Since the provided vector `numbers` is likely too small, the program tries to acceed to elements out of bound, which triggers undefined behaviors such as segmentation fault.

Two solutions:

- Push back zeros until `numbers.size()%size==0`. It modifies the vector, which is not practical for future uses and rather ugly.
- Use [`MPI_Scatterv()`](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-1.1/mpi-11-html/node72.html) !

Comment: So I haven't changed anything but for some reason now it works. I will try an implementation with MPI_Scatterv(). I know that size is not likely to be a multiple of size, but the division of two unsigned a,b variables is equivalent to floor(a/b). This is not evident it's true I will add it in as a commentary in my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! It is called an undefined behavior because the problem can remain unnoticed or the result of the program can be erroneous or the problem can die of painful death such as segmentation fault: the problem may come back latter. Even if a/b is floor(a/b), (a/b+1)*b is likely larger than a! (11/10+1)*10=20. If you use MPI_Scatterv() with correct counts and displacements, the problem will be solved!